# Problem has two reasons, wich answer should i accept?

Tags: discussion

First, it's about this question: [Drawing cube in SharpDX, wrong perspective](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75335/drawing-cube-in-sharpdx-wrong-perspective). It divided into two parts. Answer1 answered to the first part of the problem, Answer2 to the second part. Now i don't know what i should accept because only both answers together are the full solution of the problem.

Should i write an own answer with reference to the answers? Or should i accept one of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that you treated the post like a forum thread, and went back and updated it with significant new development information in response to a posted answer. This isn't what you should normally do, and it's why "debug my problem" questions (or in general questions with multiple distinct sub-questions or parts) are generally considered bad.

I removed your edit, so you can accept the answer that corresponds to the original question.

Comment: Did you also deleted one answer?

Comment: Yes (to prevent users in the future from downvoting it).